# Using UBound for Array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have a variable declared as Variant in my code

```
Dim All_WorkWeeks_Entered As Variant
```

And I am assigning the values as below

```
With Worksheets("workweeks")
    All_WorkWeeks_Entered = Application.Transpose(.Range(.Range("A1"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)))
End With
```

If my Column "A" has only one element then my All_WorkWeeks_Entered will be a string.

and in further part of the code I am using

```
For Counter = 1 To UBound(All_WorkWeeks_Entered)

Next Counter
```

UBound cannot be used for a string. How will I take All_WorkWeeks_Entered as array always?

Comment: What you are trying to do?

Comment: I want my All_WorkWeeks_Entered variable to be a Array always.

Comment: @urdearboy But it is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you transpose, you are going to end up with a zero-based array, not a one-based array. Save yourself some grief by sticking to the Lower Boundary as well as the Upper Boundary for loop iteration.

A simple row check will tell you whether there are more than a single worksheet name in column A. If it's a single value, Split on an illegal worksheet name character and you will end up with an array of one element.

```
Dim All_WorkWeeks_Entered As Variant, counter as long

With Worksheets("workweeks")
    if .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row>1 then
        All_WorkWeeks_Entered = Application.Transpose(.Range(.cells(1, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)))
    else
        All_WorkWeeks_Entered = split(.Range("A1"), "/")
    end if
End With

For Counter = LBound(All_WorkWeeks_Entered) To UBound(All_WorkWeeks_Entered)
    'do stuff with All_WorkWeeks_Entered(Counter)
Next Counter
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the single member array is presented as its type, and not as an array. A good workaround is to check the array, with the `IsArray()` function and act correspondingly.

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim alldata As Variant    
    With Worksheets(1)
        'works ok, returning array:
        'alldata = Application.Transpose(.Range("A1:A2"))

        'problematic - does not return an array, but a type not supporting Ubound():
        alldata = Application.Transpose(.Range("A1"))
    End With

    If IsArray(alldata) Then
        Debug.Print UBound(alldata)
    Else
        Debug.Print "Single member array!"
    End If

End Sub
```

In the condition, one may use some logic to return a single member array:

```
If IsArray(alldata) Then
    Debug.Print UBound(alldata)
Else
    Debug.Print "Single member array!"
    ReDim alldata(1)
    alldata(1) = Application.Transpose(Worksheets(1).Range("A1"))
    Debug.Print UBound(alldata)
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Range.Value can be either a single Variant or an Array of Variants, so you have to branch when reading the value like this:

```
With Worksheets("workweeks")
    Dim rngTarget As Range: Set rngTarget = .Range(.Range("A1"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    If IsArray(rngTarget.Value) Then
        All_WorkWeeks_Entered = Application.Transpose(rngTarget.Value)
    Else
        Dim varArray(1 To 1) As Variant: varArray(1) = rngTarget.Value
        All_WorkWeeks_Entered = varArray
    End If
End With
```

And the second loop would look better like this:

```
For Counter = LBound(All_WorkWeeks_Entered) To UBound(All_WorkWeeks_Entered)
' ...
Next Counter
```